# how to calculate sum of selected entries of a column in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sql

I want to calculate sum of all `total_purchase` values whose `ref_by` value is 1. Table name is `table_name`. Can someone please help me.

I want sql query which will return **total** (200 + 97 + 140)

[image]

Comment: Did you resolve your query?

Answer (score 0):

Query is simple, try this:

```
SELECT SUM(total_purchase) AS 'sum_total_purchase' FROM  table_name
WHERE ref_by=1
```

Try it, it will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct SQL method to get the desired result:-

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
//error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require '../app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('table_name'); //gives table name with prefix

//Select Data from table
$sql   = "SELECT SUM(total_purchase) AS 'sum_total_purchase' FROM ".$tableName."" WHERE ref_by = 1";
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```